# About progress bar in C# completely freezed

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I have a huge amount of data and windows form control to load from a file, and when the file size really is huge, I gotta use progress bar.

The thing is, progress bar works, but it will freeze immediately the moment the program starts to construct data and load it to the form.

So, is there anyway I can make it work ? I use background worker together with progress bar.

Here are a few code:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        dataGridView1.RowCount = 0;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        reading.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        setLabels();
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        reading.Visible = false;
    }
      }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        // Wait 100 milliseconds.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        // Report progress.
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
   ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    // Set the text.
    reading.Text += " at " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
}
```

Comment: Some code might be helpful here. I'm going to guess the UI is blocked and the background worker isn't being used correctly.

Comment: Something must be blocking your UI thread from updating.. can you show us a summary of your code?

Comment: -1 until you provide details.

Comment: You need to show code really so people can figure out what may be blocking your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your loading work on a separate thread and let your main thread handle updating the UI. For example:

You can kick off the worker with your file to process via:

```
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(object);
```

Then hook up a DoWork method where you do your long running task, this is where you'll report back to the UI the results/progressbar percentage:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{     
      object myObject = (object)e.Argument;
      bgWorker.ReportProgress(//YOUR FORMULA TO WORK OUT PERCENTAGE);
}
```

The call to `ReportProgress` invokes the `ProgressChanged` event where you can safely update the UI from the background thread using:

```
private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Probably he is using it:
"I use background worker together with progress bar..."

Comment: It does work. Post more of your code because you've likely screwed up your implementation of it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be blocking your UI thread from updating. Do it this way

private void updateProgressBar(int percent)

```
    {
        if (ProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateProgressBarCallback cb = new updateProgressBarCallback(updateProgressBar);
            this.Invoke(cb, new object[] { percent });
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressBar.Value = percent;
            ProgressBar.Update();
            ProgressBar.Refresh();
            ProgressBar.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```